# Owl carrousel setup incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

an agency installed in a wordpress website a new theme with everything new, and unfortunatelly Im not familiar enough with css coding to understand what happened. The website works.

The thing is I try to add more images to a carousel that is not installed trough a plug in and its coded to show that way.

The problem is that the new pictures are not formated at all.

Slide 1 Correct (done by agency) with 4 images inserted in that slide
Slide 2 Only set up for 2 images and the other images added after those are shown in 1 slide each with a 2x2 layout.

Where can I setup this? (I know coding and I understand what needs to be changed (I think)) but I cannot find where to change this. It is not on the block on the page in wordpress

Here is a small video link of what is happening:

https://share.vidyard.com/watch/MQ8Px6kzR6suthSdV5vaVz?

Answer (score 0):

The problem not in CSS section. Owl intagrated just by library css + js files.
So problem at the `php + html` area in the section where images are getted from the page custom fields. InTo the `<div class="item">` must be placed two images at once. Owl Carousel just animate all of them.
Or You do not follow some special instructions for adding pictures to this section. You may need to read the documentation for the theme. Maybe you must set special names fore img files...